# Node / Express / Angular Server side external API request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api

I am using Angular to save form input to $scope.tag. I can't make a client side external API call with the form information as a parameter, so I need to pass it to the server to do. How can i achieve this?

The steps:

1. user submits form
2. client makes request to server
3. server makes request to external API
4. server sends response back to client

How can I achieve this?

```
  $scope.tag = '';

  // client side
  $http.get('/api')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });

  // server side
  app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  request('http://externalAPI.com/' + $scope.tag, function (req, res) {
    res.json(data);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
// client side
  $http.post('/api', { tag: $scope.tag })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });

  // server side
  app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.tag);
    res.json({ status: 'success' });
  });
```

Just remember to include `app.use(bodyParser.json());` before your routing middleware.

Comment: and `npm install body-parser` and require it in the server js file since it comes separately now :P

Comment: This did not work. Using post gave me this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: it seems like the post on the client side is not being made and giving me 404 (Not Found)